# jquery prev and next adjacent sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i would like to create a pagination that add a class to the next and previous element.
i generated a code but doesn't work very well.
i think this is a very common situation, maybe i am using a wrong code.
how can i improve my code?

this is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hhebhm66/

```
  var $curr = $( "div.active" );

  $( ".prev" ).click(function() {

    if ($($curr).is(':first-child')){
      $('.prev').hide();
    }else{
      $('.next').show();
      $curr = $curr.prev();
      $( "div" ).removeClass('active');
      $curr.addClass('active');

    }
  });


  $( ".next" ).click(function() {

    if ($($curr).is(':last-child')){
      $('.next').hide();
    }else{
      $('.prev').show();
      $curr = $curr.next();
      $( "div" ).removeClass('active');
      $curr.addClass('active');

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic can be improved by simply using `prev()` or `next()` and checking that an element was retrieved. If it wasn't, then just get the `first()` or `last()` singling `div` in the set. Try this:

```
$(".prev").click(function () {
    var $active = $('.active').removeClass('active');
    var $prev = $active.prev('div');
    if ($prev.length == 0)
           $prev = $active.siblings('div').last();
    $prev.addClass('active');
});


$(".next").click(function () {
    var $active = $('.active').removeClass('active');
    var $next = $active.next('div');
    if ($next.length == 0)
           $next = $active.siblings('div').first();
    $next.addClass('active');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hhebhm66/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using an index for the active dom element would be even easier:

```js
var index = 5;

$('button').click(function() {
  var lastIndex = index;
  index += this.className == 'prev' ? -1 : 1;
  var thisChild = $('div:nth-child(' + index + ')');
  if (thisChild.get(0)) {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    thisChild.addClass('active');
  } else {
    index = lastIndex;
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px blue solid;
  padding: 2px;
}
span {
  font-size: 14px;
}
p {
  clear: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class='active'></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<p>
  <button class='prev'>Go to Prev</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class='next'>Go to next</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to show/hide blocks before checking for first/last. Also it's better to wrap blocks into common container to avoid accidental iteration on irrelevant siblings.

```js
var $blocks = $('.blocks > div'),
    $curr = $blocks.filter(".active");

$(".prev").click(function () {
    $curr = $curr.prev();
    $blocks.removeClass('active');
    $curr.addClass('active');
    
    if ($curr.is(':first-child')) {
        $('.prev').hide();
    }
    else $('.next').show();
});


$(".next").click(function () {
    $curr = $curr.next();
    $blocks.removeClass('active');
    $curr.addClass('active');
    if ($curr.is(':last-child')) {
        $('.next').hide();
    }
    else $('.prev').show();
});
```

```css
.blocks div {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px blue solid;
    padding: 2px;
}
p {
    clear: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blocks">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class='active'></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<p>
    <button class='prev'>Go to Prev</button>
</p>
<p>
    <button class='next'>Go to Next</button>
</p>
```